# Fixed background on iPhone Safari

Tags: iphone, safari, css

iPhone Safari seems to have some sort of problem whereby a page with css like this:

```
body {
   background: #000 url(fixedimage.png) fixed repeat-x;
}
```

...doesn't actually lead to a fixed image. It scrolls as the user scrolls.

I've seen plenty of people kvetching about this on the internets, but no real solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have this issue as well, and I found the doctyper solution as well but, but am unable to modify it successfully to make the background stay fixed while content scrolls up and down.  it seems to be stuck on the fact that it needs both a header and footer scroll areas..  where you able to get it to work using doctyper's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this site. But have not tried it out yet. look pretty complex.
http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/