# body's background with fixed position not showing on iPhone

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixed background on iPhone Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010176/fixed-background-on-iphone-safari)

It's very strange. The background does show up on Desktop and Android phones but it doesn't show up on iPhone.

**HTML:**

```
<body class="customer-account-login">
```

**CSS:**

```
.customer-account-login {
    background: url(../images/join-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -10;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Try adding commas like so `background: url('../images/join-bg.jpg')` and check your `path`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Its always advisable to use PNGs in iPhone

2) Check image name, its case sensitive

3) try giving width and height in PX and then check

let me know if still dont work